# Can't link a stylesheet

Tags: css

I am building a web application and trying to link a stylesheet to my app. Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bubble</title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/main.css">   
<body>
```

The app is located in the direct DrDenver/blog. The full style sheet is located in DrDenver/blog/public.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/1650337

Comment: what error do you get in console or network tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Doesn't matter where "the app" is located, what matters is where this HTML document is located in relation to the stylesheet. If the document is in public/, then ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line to my app.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/public"));
```

And updated the code on my header.ejs to after moving the main.css to public/stylesheet directory.

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot and slash. you are looking above the dir instead of within.
Try This.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/main.css">
```

Comment: I tried that I got this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: move your style sheet to the same folder as your html and see if it works.  remember to connect like this href = "main.css".  Remove public.   Sometimes if you are using a App it will have problems with the dir.

Comment: If that dont work copy and paste both to your desktop and check it.

Comment: I am using c9 and I placed both the app.js and main.css into the same folder and I am still getting the 404 error messages.